# Is there a way to find out specifically why a flight was delayed?

Tags: online-resources, airlines, delays

Is there some tool I can use to figure out why a flight is delayed?

Specifically I'm trying to see why the 2nd leg of the flight AI 951 is delayed by about an hour nearly every day, though it takes off on time.

Comment: It takes off on time, but reaches 1hr late?

Comment: @MeNoTalk Yup departure is on time but arrival is about an hour late daily for the past 1 week

Comment: @MarkMayo The answer there points to flightstats which does not mention the cause of the delay anywhere

Comment: I'm not  sure about the answer, but the question certainly seems exactly the same :/  What about flightaware? I'm personally guessing most airlines won't publish the data, it's pretty hard to automatically push the reason out each time, without having it questioned. Jetstar cancelled one on me and when I asked, all I get told is 'technical difficulties'.  What are those? They refused to clarify.  So I doubt it's going to be publically available, except in the event of something like a crash or accident or awful weather prior.

Comment: @MarkMayo Questions can only be dupes if they have answers, and the sole answer in that was deleted.

Comment: @jpatokal it wasn't deleted when I linked to it...Ankur removed it 14 hours ago.  Correct decision though, I feel.

Comment: Why can't a question without an answer be a duplicate? If there is no answer to the original question, there is no reason to assume that repeating the question will help.

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo The Stack Exchange software won't let you close as dupe unless the duped-to question has an answer. (Try it!)